# Groovy Jenkins: Evaluate BUILD_LOG_REGEX and check if empty before sending email

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, build-automation

I have a finally clause in my JenkinsFile which is like

```
finally{
 def script_regex = '${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^The module", maxMatches=5, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true}'
 if (script_regex){
        emailext to: "y@z.com",
                 subject: "some subj",
                 body: script_regex
    }
}
```

I tried using echo(script_regex) but it gives

```
'${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^The module", maxMatches=5, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true}'
```

as a string instead of evaluating the regex. Although, it works fine inside exailext. Is there a way to check if this regex returns an empty string? and only send email when the regex returns a matching string. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If regex does not match, what is the value of script_regex?

Comment: Try enclosing the value in triple-double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of research, I found that the `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` variable is defined by the `emailext` plugin. Hence, we cannot use outside it.

Instead we can use something like `manager.logContains('<regex>')` and this will check your build log and return a boolean value indicating whether the required string is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

That variable is actually defined by the https://plugins.jenkins.io/token-macro/ plugin, which is part of several other plugins, including the https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-name-setter/ plugin.